# Error While Minified HTML File Using GULP

Tags: javascript, html

I am an iOS developer & currently I am trying to minify my all html files. I am using gulp & below is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier');

gulp.task('minify', function() {
          gulp.src('./*.html')
          .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
          });
```

When I am trying to run 'gulp' on terminal I am getting following error

```
Test2s-MacBook-Pro:TestFile test2$ gulp
[14:43:36] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/TestFile/gulpfile.js
[14:43:36] **Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile**
[14:43:36] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
Test2s-MacBook-Pro:TestFile test2$
```

can any one suggest my what am I doing wrong?   I also seen this links but no help  https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1155

Please suggest me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you haven't mentioned the default task for gulp
Try running gulp minify command instead of gulp

or use

```
 gulp.task('default', ['minify']);
```